# check if index is out of bounds to satisfy if conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

Hello I am practicing working with 2d arrays in  c++ and my question is for example if I want to check if 4 has either 0 or 11 to the north , east, south, west  as neighbour it should return false.
this is my if

```
if((grid[0-1][0] == 0 || grid[0-1][0] == 11 ) && 
 (grid[0+1][0] == 0 || grid[0+1][0] == 11 )  &&
(grid[0][0+1] == 0 || grid[0][0+1] ==11)  &&
 (grid[0][0-1] == 0 || grid[0][0-1] ==11 ))
{
    return false;
}
```

Now my problem is since west of 4 and north of four is out of bounds it will never return false.
How could I optimise my if condition to make it return false?
This is my 2d array

```
int grid[ROW][COL] = {{ 4, 11, 1, 1 },
                  { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                  { 0, 1, 5, 0},
                  { 0, 5, 0,0 } };
```

Comment: Before checking the neighbour's values, you can check whether those neighbours actually exist. You can compute that from the bounds of the array.

Comment: *How could I optimise my if condition* -- Let's see your unoptimized `if` condition, because the one you posted is totally wrong.  That code you posted cannot work without invoking undefined behavior.  `grid[0-1][0]` is not a valid array access.

Comment: Give the board a 1 cell border on all edges and popular the border cells with an invalid value. If you do this no special test are needed for out-of-bounds checks.  eg an 8x8 chess board would be 10x10 with the border cells populated with an invalid piece value.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR
you are missing boundary conditions

```
// Boundary Conditions
    if( i == ROW || j == COL || i < 0 || j < 0 )
        return false;
```

---

Based on the question the matrix is defined as

```
#define ROW 4
#define COL 4

int grid[ROW][COL] = {{ 4, 11, 1, 1 },
                      { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                      { 0, 1, 5, 0},
                     { 0, 5, 0,0 } };
```

given a cell at `row i` and `col j` denoted by cordinated `i, j` the visualization in a 2-D array for that will look like this

```
i-1, j-1    i-1, j      i-1,j+1
  i, j-1      i, j        i,j+1
i+1, j-1    i+1, j      i+1,j+1
```

from above we can now deduce the corresponding cordinates/points reference to given `i,j`

```
i,j ---> North( i-1, j  )
i,j ---> South( i+1, j  )
i,j --->  East( i  , j+1)
i,j --->  West( i  , j-1)
```

now we can write a small function to check if a given value at any cell denoted by i and j is true or not, this below function does similar .. checks if supplied coordinates are within boundary and if the value at `grid[j]j]` matches what we need to match

```
bool Check( int grid[ROW][COL], int expected, int i, int j )
{
    // Boundary Conditions
    if( i == ROW || j == COL || i < 0 || j < 0 )
        return false;

    return ( grid[i][j] == expected );
}
```

Now time to put the North, South, West, East calculation to code and expose them as nice functions,

```
bool northHas( int grid[ROW][COL], int expected, int i, int j )
{
    return check(grid, expected, i-1, j );
}

bool southHas( int grid[ROW][COL], int expected, int i, int j )
{
    return check(grid, expected, i+1, j );
}


bool eastHas( int grid[ROW][COL], int expected, int i, int j )
{
    return check(grid, expected, i, j+1 );
}


bool westHas( int grid[ROW][COL], int expected, int i, int j )
{
    return check(grid, expected, i, j-1 );
}
```

each of these functions above exposes a nicer interface to deal with what logic program wants to do

```
if( (northHas( grid, 0, i, j ) || northHas( grid, 11, i, j)) && 
    ( eastHas( grid, 0, i, j ) ||  eastHas( grid, 11, i, j)) &&
    (southHas( grid, 0, i, j ) || southHas( grid, 11, i, j)) &&
    ( westHas( grid, 0, i, j ) ||  westHas( grid, 11, i, j)) )
{
    return false
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. `eastHas( grid, i, j, 0)` shouldn't it be `eastHas( grid, 0, i, j)` ?

Comment: so for example the array looks like this `{{ 4, 11, 1, 1 },
                                                                 { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                                                                 { 0, 1, 5, 0},
                                                                 { 0, 5, 0,0 } };` it won't return false am I right ?