# checking the values of the neighboring points

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently working on a code that checks the giving index neighbors (north, west, east, south) and if the neighbors have the value 0 or 11 it should return false. The start point is 0,0 which has the value 4.
This is my test function.

```
 bool testG(int grid[ROW][COL], int row, int col) {
         if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= ROW || col >= COL)
             return false;
         return grid[row][col] == 0 || grid[row][col] == 11;
    }
```

this is my query:

```
if(testG(grid,-1,0) && testG(grid,0,-1) && testG(grid,1,0) && testG(grid,0,1)) 
{ 
  return false;
}
```

and this is my 2d array that should return false if the function is called.

```
int grid[ROW][COL] {{ 4, 11, 1, 1 },
                  { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
                  { 0, 1, 5, 0},
                  { 0, 5, 0,0 } };
```

if the array looks like this it should return true.

```
 int grid[ROW][COL] {{ 4, 11, 1, 1 },
                      { 1, 1, 1, 0 },
                      { 0, 1, 5, 0},
                      { 0, 5, 0,0 } };
```

My problem is the first two parts of the if query`if(testG(grid,-1,0) && testG(grid,0,-1)` this  won't return true for the 2d array above because to the west and north of the number 4 is out of bounds.
How can I optimize my code so that one part of the index is left out if it's out of bounds but if the other queries are correct it should return false?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about making `testG` return `true` for out-of-bounds query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [check if index is out of bounds to satisfy if conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941450/check-if-index-is-out-of-bounds-to-satisfy-if-conditions)

Comment: @MikeCAT THANK YOU SOOO MUCH !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
struct location {
  int row = 0;
  int col = 0;
};
int get( int grid[ROW][COL], location l ) {
  return grid[l.row][l.col];
}
std::vector<location> get_adjacents( location l ) {
  std::vector<location> retval;
  if (l.row-1 >= 0) retval.push_back( {l.row-1, l.col} );
  if (l.row+1 < ROW) retval.push_back( {l.row+1, l.col} );
  if (l.col-1 >= 0) retval.push_back( {l.row, l.col-1} );
  if (l.col+1 < COL) retval.push_back( {l.row, l.col+1} );
  return retval;
}
bool testG_adjacents( int grid[ROW][COL], location l ) {
  for (auto adjacent : get_adjacents(l) ) 
    if (!testG(grid, adjacent.row, adjacent.col))
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

this attempts to split the adjacent in-bounds logic from the test logic.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to judge if each cells are one of:

- out-of-bounds
- have value 0
- have value 11

To realize this, the function `testG` should return `true` for not only the "have value 0" and "have value 11" case but also "out-of-bounds" case.

```
bool testG(int grid[ROW][COL], int row, int col) {
    if (row < 0 || col < 0 || row >= ROW || col >= COL)
        return true; // return true for out-of-bounds case
    return grid[row][col] == 0 || grid[row][col] == 11;
}
```